# Match a pattern by ignoring brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I would like to know the first position of a pattern. But it should be found only, if it's not enclosed by with brackets.

Example String: "`This is a (first) test with the first hit`"

I want to know the position of the second `first` => 32. To match it, the `(first)` must be ignored, because it's enclosed in brackets.

I tried this:

```
preg_match(
  '/^(.*?)(first)/',
  "This is a (first) test with the first hit",
  $matches
);
$result = strlen( $matches[2] );
```

It works fine, but the result is the position of the first match (11).

So I need to change the `.*?`.

I tried to replace it with `.(?:\(.*?\))*?` in the hope, all characters inside the brackets will be ignored.

But this does not match at all.

Comment: `'/^(.*?)(first)(?![^()]*\))/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?<!\()first(?!\))/
```

You can use the negative look ahead ?! and negative look behind operator ?

```
preg_match(
  '/(?<!\()first(?!\))/',
  "This is a (first) test with the first hit",
  $matches
);
```

this matches only the text not enclosed in brackets or you can just check the beginning of the word if do not need any word starting with a bracket

```
/(?<!\()first/
```

Comment: This misses several matches. Did you test? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nby6IS/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression

```
(?!\(first\)).\K\bfirst\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nby6IS/4/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?!          # begin a negative lookahead
  \(first\)  # match '(first)'
)            # end negative lookahead
.            # match any character
\K           # forget all matched so far (the previous character)
\bfirst\b    # match 'first' surrounded by word breaks
```

If the string contains no substring `(first)` each substring `first` (surrounded by word breaks) is matched. Depending on requirements, only the first match may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\(first\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|first`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EhM8X/1)

Comment: Beautiful! My only suggestion is to change `|first` to `|\bfirst\b` so that `firstly` is not matched. Most readers, including this one, will not understand the functions of `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`. I'm sure we would all appreciate an explanation (with an edit of your answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
/(?<!\()\bfirst\b(?!\))/g
```

**(first)** are ignored but {first} or [first] will be matched (only the first word). xxfirstxx is also ignored because of the word boundary **\b**

[Another sample](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7105&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9416&link=[[%22B510C1D203054C4D98B0215AAE499B5Ezoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7105]])

Comment: One problem: this will not match the second `first` in `The (first) is the (first time`.

Comment: Try this: `\bfirst(?!\))|(?<!\()first\b`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nby6IS/5/)